# Threshold value for nodes similarity

Tags: clustering, similarities, graph-theory, threshold, jaccard-similarity

I am working on an algorithm for community detection on complex systems, where those systems are modeled as graphs. To form community i need to find similarity between nodes.

I am using **Jaccard similarity**. Normally the similarity value is between 0 and 1. However to detect community, i need to determine a certain threshold value.

My question is:

How can I define an appropriate threshold value? There is some methods to do that? If not, what is the best threshold value that I can use it to find similar nodes?